# String parsing functions in NSIS

Tags: string, nsis

Is there any string parsing functions in NSIS other than StrCpy and StrLen?

Or a plugin that has methods like strstr, strcmp, find, contains etc.

Comment: Yes, you are right but I need more that that. Like the usual string methods in C/C++, C# to be able to do string parsing easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[StrFunc](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/StrFunc), included in the default install, contains several functions:

```
${StrCase}
${StrClb}
${StrIOToNSIS}
${StrLoc}
${StrNSISToIO}
${StrRep}
${StrStr}
${StrStrAdv}
${StrTok}
${StrTrimNewLines}
${StrSort}
```